# Passing parameter for parent::__constructor() function while instantiating an object in php

Tags: php, oop

Hello everybody I'm very new to Object Oriented Programming in php. So sometimes i need help while learning OOP in PHP. 
Here's a class named parentClass i have with a few method and properties like:

```
    class parentClass 
    {
    public $fname;
    public $lname;
     public $age;

    function __construct($title, $firstName, $lastName, $age,$address)  
      {
        $this->title    = $title;
        $this->fname    = $firstName;
        $this->lname   = $lastName;
        $this->age      = $age;
        $this->address = $address;

      }



     public function getFullName()
    {
        return $this->fname . " " . $this->lname. " ". $this->address;
     }
    }
```

I also have a child class named childClass which extends parentClass with few another properties and methods and also have another _constructor function in it. And then I Called parentClass's method and properties with parent::__construct

```
    class childClass extends parentClass
    {

    function __construct($title1, $firstName1, $mainName1, $age1)   
    {
     parent::__construct($title, $firstName, $lastName, $age, $address)
        $this->title1   = $title1;
        $this->fname1   = $firstName1;
        $this->lname1   = $mainName1;
        $this->age1     = $age1;

     }

    function getFullName1()
    {
        return $this->fname1 . " " . $this->lname1 . " ". $this->address;
     }
    }
```

So now I have to pass argument to parentClass's construcotr function's parameter. And I want getFullName1 method to return data with address. 
if I write:

```
         $obj = new childClass("title", "Rohim", "Uddin", 50);
```

Here i can pass argument in only childClass's __constructor function parameter.

My question is where to pass argument for parentClass's construcotr function's parameter? more specific for $address parameter;
Thanks in advance. And I'm sorry for any mistake.

Comment: You don't need to create the child constructor. Then the parent constructor will be automatically called with the same parameters.

Comment: But my child constuctor's parameters are different form the parent constructor's parameter and I need them to work with my child class's method. @Amarnasan

Comment: Then you must make up a value for the parameter `$address` and use it along with the child class parameters to call the parent with `parent::__construct($title, $firstName, $lastName, $age, 'anyAddress')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First a little explaination of what inheritence means. The fact here is that `childClass` is an instance of `parentClass`. 
So what does that mean? That means that `childClass` can use all the variables and methods of `parentClass` as long the access modifier is `public` or `protected`.
You choosed the create public variables, thus that mean that you can use the variables defined in `parentClass` in your `childClass`.
That means this will work perfecly fine:

```
$instance = new childClass("Title","Firstname","Lastname",etc.);
echo $instance->fname; //echo's "Firstname" (according to the code below)
```

If you use inheritance, the child constructor need to receive the parameters you want to pass through the parent's constructor.

Your almost there, i putted some comments in the code below:

```
class parentClass 
{
    //Create the title variable if you want to use it here
    public $title;
    public $fname;
    public $lname;
    public $age;
    //Create the address variable if you want to use it here
    public $address;

    function __construct($title, $firstName, $lastName, $age,$address)  
    {
        $this->title    = $title;
        $this->fname    = $firstName;
        $this->lname    = $lastName;
        $this->age      = $age;
        $this->address  = $address;

    }

    public function getFullName()
    {
        return $this->fname . " " . $this->lname. " ". $this->address;
    }
}

class childClass extends parentClass
{

    //It's not necessary to add an `1` or something else to this parameters. Just give them clean names.
    //If you want to pass the `$address` variable through the constructor you should add this parameter to this constructor. Since it's the constructor the variable won't be filled elsewhere.
    function __construct($title, $firstName, $lastName, $age, $address)   
    {
        parent::__construct($title, $firstName, $lastName, $age, $address)

        //This code is too much. In the line above you already passed the variables to the parent constructor. There they are handled by the parents constructor. 
        //As i explained above you can access these variables, thus it makes no sence to create new variables here or to override the just-setted variables.
        /*$this->title1   = $title1;
        $this->fname1   = $firstName1;
        $this->lname1   = $mainName1;
        $this->age1     = $age1;*/
    }

    //Why you write this function here? Because `childClass` inherits from `parentClass` you can just use the methods of `parentClass`. If you call `childClass->getFullName()` the `getFullName` function in `parentClass` will be executed.
    //It will return the same values as you are returning here. Just leave this function. Only create this function if you want to override the default `parentClass->getFullName` behaviour. Then leave the 1 so it will be `getFullName` instead of `getFullName1`
    /*function getFullName1()
    {
        return $this->fname1 . " " . $this->lname1 . " ". $this->address;
    }*/
}
```

So what's happening at the end?

```
$instance = new childClass("My Title", "Stefan", "Pols", 25, "My Adress 1");
//`childClass` constructor is called here.
//The first line (`parent::__construct`) will pass the variables to the parentClass. There they are set to the right variables.

echo $instance->getFullName();
//Compiler tries to find the method `getFullName()` in `childClass`. It doesn't exist.
//Compiler sees it inherits from `parentClass` so it's going to search the method `getFullName()` in `parentClass`
//It does exist. Since we setted the variables during the creation of the `$instance` object (through the constructor) this function will return the right values.

Output: `$this->fname . " " . $this->lname. " ". $this->address;`  > Stefan Pols My Adress 1
```

Comment: Really nice and helpful explanation. Thanks S.Pls I accepted it as an answer. Thanks again.